# AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0 linux Daemon: Daemon startup failed

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, reactxp

I am trying to get an react-native app to be build in a docker container. (Based on azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:8 with openjdk 8)
But on building with gradle I get the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
[...]
```

Build gradle and config is fresh generated by `create-rx-app`

Comment: same error on Windows + Jenkins